# declaration of List outside of the method: leetcode 965 Univalued Binary Tree

Tags: list, arraylist, binary-tree

I don't understand why we need to declare the List vals outside of the method?
[image]

Can someone explain List vals;  and vals = new ArrayList();?
why can we new Arraylist like this: vals = new ArrayList();

My initial way of solving this problem is:
[image]

Comment: Please.... don't post images of text, code or error messages. Type the text.

Answer (score 0):

`dfs` needs access to `vals`. In your version of the code the scope of `vals` is limited to the `isUnitvalTree` function. It is a local variable there.

The first code you presented solves this by extending the scope of that variable to the instance of the class. Because this instance will be used to call your function `usUnivalTree` multiple times, it is then necessary to clear the array as it will still have the values from a previous run. That's why that version has the assignment `vals = new ArrayList()`.

Another way to give `dfs` access to that array, is to define it locally like you did, but then to pass it as argument to `dfs` -- which should then have an extra parameter for receiving the reference to that array. And each recursive call should then also pass that array.